# What motherboard for a Core i7 920 Processor?

Tags: motherboard, intel-core-i7

I am wanting to build a really nice PC, price is not to important as I will buy pieces every week or whatever it takes until I get everything I need.  I am not a gamer but I would like to watch video and have 3-4 monitors.  I do a lot of programming and use a lot of big programs so I would like to go all out and get a lot of Memory, probably at least 12gb but possibly more even as I see many boards support up to 24gb now.  Will be using Windows 7.  I have decided to go with the 
Core i7 920 Processor BX80601920.

Based on what I posted above, can you please recommend some good motherboards I should look at ?  Also some good places to purchase them online.

Thanks for any help, tips, etc.

Answer (score 1):

How many memory will you use ? I think they'll be DDR3 SDRAM.

I recommend for [ASUS Core i7 Motherboards](http://www.google.com/products?q=ASUS+core+i7+motherboard&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=GSOPS8OFM5e80gTnyJDnDA&sa=X&oi=product_result_group&ct=title&resnum=3&ved=0CCEQrQQwAg). 
among, then, the most suitable one is [ASUS P6T6 WS Revolution - motherboard](https://www.eio.com/p-18692-asus-p6t6-ws-revolution-with-nf200-3xpcie-true-x16-lga-1366-intel-x58-atx-intel-motherboard.aspx)

it supports up to Corei7 Extreme. on board      6 x Hi-Speed USB , Serial ATA-300 - connector(s): 2 x 7pin external SATA - 2 device(s) - RAID 0 / RAID 1 / RAID 10 / RAID 5 , max memory supported 24 GB (DDR3 1600(O.C)/1333).

for budget one, it's quite good. [ASUS LGA1156](http://www.provantage.com/asus-p7h55-m-pro~7ASUS1WF.htm) (unde $100).

Hope this helps anyway.

Comment: The LGA1156 motherboard is not suitable for the i7-920, because the 920 is an LGA1366 processor.